# Is there any way to find out mouse left button up event outside of an element in wpf?

Tags: wpf, mouseleftbuttonup

I will define an event for my border element that relize mouse left button up outside of this element.

Comment: pls explain in detail... more explanation will give you more answers

Comment: why this question id down voted. it seems to be a good question and also from a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get mouse up event outside the element who received mouse down, if on the mouse down you call `element.CaptureMouse()` (and on mouse up, do not forget to call `element.ReleaseMouseCapture()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
        Mouse.Capture (this,CaptureMode.SubTree);
        AddHandler ();

    private void AddHandler()
    {
        AddHandler (Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent,new MouseButtonEventHandler (HandleClickOutsideOfControl),true);
    }
```